# Adding details linked structures

Tags: c

I wrote this code: (Structures above and functions below)

```
list * add_student(slist * students, char * name, int id) {
    slist * temp, * adder;

    if (!(adder = (slist * )
        malloc(sizeof(slist)))) exit(1);

    student * data;

    if (!(data = (student * )
        malloc(sizeof(student)))) exit(1);

    data - > name = name;
    data - > id = id;
    data - > courses = NULL;
    adder - > info = data;
    adder - > next = NULL;

    if (!students) {
        return adder;
    }

    for (temp = students; temp - > next; temp = temp - > next);
    temp - > next = adder;
    return students;
}
```

**The structures are:**

```
typedef struct course {
    char *title;
    int  number;
    struct slist *students;
} course;

typedef struct slist {
    student      *info;
    struct slist *next;
} slist;

typedef struct clist {
    course       *info;
    struct clist *next;
} clist;
```

The first function is supposed to add student to the student list.
Its adding the student but if I am trying to put another student, the name is replacing the name of the first one (only the name not the number).

I cant find a mistake in the code ill really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't C#. Please use the correct language tag next time.

Comment: Tagged c#, but clearly not c#.

Comment: Your problem is most likely the way you call the function. Show that code as well. My guess is that `char * name` keeps pointing to the same variable (e.g. an array) that you change again and again.

Comment: `data - > name = name;` --> `data - > name = strdup(name);`

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory for the name and copy it from name argument:

```
list * add_student(slist * students, char * name, int id) {
  slist * temp, * adder;
  if (!(adder = (slist * ) malloc(sizeof(slist)))) exit(1);
  student * data;
  if (!(data = (student * ) malloc(sizeof(student)))) exit(1);
  if (!(data->name = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name)+1)))) exit(1);
  strcpy(data->name, name);
  data->id = id;
  data->courses = NULL;
  adder->info = data;
  adder->next = NULL;
  if (!students) {
    return adder;
  }
  for (temp = students; temp - > next; temp = temp - > next);
  temp - > next = adder;
  return students;
}
```

Comment: Could be correct but I'm not sure it is a good idea to guess about code that OP didn't post

Comment: @4386427, I am sure that the issue is because name argument has exactly same pointer between two calls of the function, but since I don't have 50 points yet I can't ask him a question in the comment.

Comment: I cant change the arguments its part of the assignment.

Comment: @Eden, do you mean `data->name` must have exactly same pointer as it was passed to the function in the `name` argument? Then your code is fine. As I tried to explain earlier the issue is with something else, that calls your function. Most probably it just copies names of students into same memory block and passes pointer to exactly same address every time.

Comment: Hey, im having trouble again.
im trying this function to register a student and remove him.

Comment: @Eden, sorry, I copied a line and forgot to change one thing. I updated the code (`if (!(data = (char * ) malloc(strlen(name)+1))) exit(1);` should actually be `if (!(data->name = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name)+1)))) exit(1);`) I also added sizeof(char), which would make your code unicode-friendly :)

Comment: @Viacheslav hey i wrote another post because i could put it in a comment.

Comment: @Eden, you should have given a link then :). If my answer to this question is what you needed, then you should accept it. Meanwhile I'll check out what you have in your other question.

Comment: Thank you very much. The other question is on another subject