# Got stuck with linked lists

Tags: c

I wrote this code: (structures above and functions below)
I'm trying this function to register a student and remove him.

```
void reg_student(slist *students, clist *courses, int id, int number){
slist *temp;
clist*temp1;
student *reg;
course *addit;
for (temp = students; temp->info->id!=id; temp = temp->next);
reg = temp->info;// the student we want to register.
for (temp1 = courses; temp1->info->number != number; temp1 = temp1->next);
addit = temp1->info;//the course to add.
//adding the course to the student courses list.
reg->courses = add_course(reg->courses, addit->title, addit->number);
//adding the student to the course students list.
addit->students = add_student(addit->students, reg->name, reg->id);

void unreg_student(slist *students, int id, int number){
slist *temp;
clist *temp1;
student *studenttoremove;
course *coursetoremove;
for (temp = students; temp->info->id != id; temp = temp->next);
studenttoremove = temp->info;// the student we want to delete.
for (temp1 = studenttoremove->courses; temp1->info-> number != number; temp1 = temp1->next);
coursetoremove = temp1->info;//the course we want to delete.
studenttoremove->courses = remove_course(studenttoremove->courses, coursetoremove);
temp1->info->students = remove_student(temp1->info->students, studenttoremove);
```

}

```
slist* remove_student(slist*students, student* s1){
slist* temp=students,*temp1;
if (temp->info == s1){
    if (!(temp->next)){
        free(temp);
        return NULL;
    }
    temp1 = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return temp1;
}
for (temp = students; temp->next->info != s1; temp = temp->next);
temp1 = temp->next;
temp = temp1->next;
free(temp1);
return students;
```

}

```
clist* remove_course(clist*courses, course * c1){
clist* temp=courses, *temp1;
if (temp->info == c1){
    if (!(temp->next)){
        free(temp);
        return NULL;
    }
    temp1 = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return temp1;
}
for (temp = courses; temp->next->info != c1; temp = temp->next);
temp1 = temp->next;
temp = temp1->next;
free(temp1);
return courses;
```

}

`    the structures are:

```
    typedef struct course {
    char *title;
    int  number;
    struct slist *students;
} course;

typedef struct slist {
    student      *info;
    struct slist *next;
} slist;

typedef struct clist {
    course       *info;
    struct clist *next;
} clist;
```

The functions are supposed to add and remove a student and course.
the register works fine. but when I'm trying to remove a student, the course is removed from the student courses list, but the student isn't removed from the course list. When i debugged it i saw the remove function is getting a NULL as the student list.. and i cant see why.
Thank you.

Comment: Why did you tag C# when this is C or C++?

Comment: You asked this exact question a few hours ago and you have been clearly instructed to use the appropriate language tag. Why did you repeat the question without improving its quality as suggested?

Comment: is it c++ - its definitely not c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding details linked structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312712/adding-details-linked-structures)

Comment: Please use existing [`LinkedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of trying to shoehorn C++ code into some presumable C# app.

Comment: Im sorry about the tag i didnt notice.

Comment: Think about simplifying your code. You rarely need more than one level of `if`. It gets very confusing to look at or work with.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue in these two functions was at the very end, where you have `temp = temp1->next`. It should be `temp->next = temp1->next`.

```
slist* remove_student(slist*students, student* s1){
    slist* temp=students,*temp1;
    if (temp->info == s1){
        if (!(temp->next)){
            free(temp);
            return NULL;
        }
        temp1 = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return temp1;
    }
    for (temp = students; temp->next->info != s1; temp = temp->next);
    if (!temp->next)
        return students;
    temp1 = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp1->next;
    free(temp1);
    return students;
}

clist* remove_course(clist*courses, course * c1){
    clist* temp=courses, *temp1;
    if (temp->info == c1){
        if (!(temp->next)){
            free(temp);
            return NULL;
        }
        temp1 = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return temp1;
    }
    for (temp = courses; temp->next->info != c1; temp = temp->next);
    if (!temp->next)
        return courses;
    temp1 = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp1->next;
    free(temp1);
    return courses;
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I totally missed that. The other issue is in `unreg_student()` itself. The reason is that when calling `remove_student()` you pass `temp1->info->student` as first argument, while memory block that is pointed to by `temp1` is already freed by previously called `remove_course()`. This means you are playing with memory access violation. What is stored in the `temp1` may be no longer what you expect and may not even be accessible. However you can fix this really easily. Just replace the last line of `unreg_student()` to `coursetoremove->students = remove_student(coursetoremove->students, studenttoremove);`:

```
void unreg_student(slist *students, int id, int number){
    slist *temp;
    clist *temp1;
    student *studenttoremove;
    course *coursetoremove;
    for (temp = students; temp->info->id != id; temp = temp->next);
    studenttoremove = temp->info;// the student we want to delete.
    for (temp1 = studenttoremove->courses; temp1->info->number != number; temp1 = temp1->next);
    coursetoremove = temp1->info;//the course we want to delete.
    studenttoremove->courses = remove_course(studenttoremove->courses, coursetoremove);
    coursetoremove->students = remove_student(coursetoremove->students, studenttoremove);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Viacheslav , thank you for your help, I still cant figure out why in the unreg function the remove_student function is getting NULL in the courses although the student is in the courses students list.

Comment: @Eden, I've found the issue and updated the answer. Check it out.